# ORS Tools in QGIS produces "Quota Exceeded" and "Over Query Limit" Error Messages

Tags: qgis, network-analyst

So I am trying to use the ORS Tools plug in QGIS to calculate the drive time and distances between two sets of addresses. I have saved the origin and destination addresses as separate point layers but each layer has a set of matching ID values that I hope to use for later joins. I have done similar operations in the past with no problems.

However, whenever I run the tool I keep getting "Quota Exceeded" and "Over Query Limit" error messages and I do not get the route layer that the ORS Tools plugin usually produces. I suspect the issue might be with the API but I am not sure. I was curious if anyone else has had this problem before.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that the problem is that the API from ORS website limits how much data you can process in a given day. However if you have large datasets you can run ORS in Docker and there are no limits on much data you can process, which is what I am currently doing.